# How can I make react render the new state modifications after I have updated the state with hooks and context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I made an AddMovie component that will add a movie to the current state in the context component. And I made it update the number of the movies after adding each movie, and I also made it add the latest added movie to the DOM along with the rest of the movies. The problem is that the name of the latest movie it is not displayed with the other movies.

I can always make it work if I make this with traditional classes, but I want to find out what is the reason for this behaviour. 
There are some simple components, not much to read through and you can check it out here:

**https://codesandbox.io/s/v661kq4zx3**

The thing is that as I add more movies the number of items in the movies array from the context component is getting updated. The problem that I want to solve is making the newly added movie get displayed with the others.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bind the title of the new movie to the `name` attribute, but in your `Movie` component you use the `title` attribute to display the `title`.

Just change the `addMovie` function inside the `AddMovie` component to save the new title to the `title` attribute.

```
const addMovie = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    setMovies(prevMovies => [
      ...prevMovies,
      { title: name, overview: "OK", id: movies.length + 1 } // <--- Here was previously `name` instead of `title`
    ]);
};
```

Comment: i have also found the problem is in title and name . by changing the name with title the list start updating

Comment: Yes, title was the property, not name. Can't believe it was just that. I was expecting this to be some intricate problem related to the way I used hooks. Thanks

Comment: Working codesandbox of the above: https://codesandbox.io/s/6vmol153o3. @Tarasi - Utilize `useCallback` and make sure empty submissions don't add movies.

Comment: Interesting solution, do you reckon useCallback is better to use than the above solution ?

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
const addMovie = evt => {
 evt.preventDefault();
 setMovies(prevMovies => [
   ...prevMovies,
   { title: name, overview: "OK", id: movies.length + 1 }
 ]);
};
```